# How to set up a PPTP Server on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I really like to make PPTP VPN connection base on Ubuntu, (non-encrypted) but I do not know how to do this. I think I have to install ppp first but after that my main problem is on configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [great tutorial](http://www.larmeir.com/2010/03/setting-up-a-pptp-vpn-server-on-debian-and-ubuntu/) that still works on Ubuntu 12.04 - I just used it on the latest LTS version. Do what is said there, and then change some options in `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`:

```
# Encryption
# Debian: on systems with a kernel built with the package
# kernel-patch-mppe >= 2.4.2 and using ppp >= 2.4.2, ...
# {{{
#refuse-pap
#refuse-chap
#refuse-mschap
# Require the peer to authenticate itself using MS-CHAPv2 [Microsoft
# Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol, Version 2] authentication.
#require-mschap-v2
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
# (note that MPPE requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
#require-mppe-128
nomppe
# }}}
```

There's a lot more options to configure `pppd` to your needs. Have a look at `man pppd`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another](http://globalcynic.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/pptpd-ubuntu-12-04-vps-fail2ban/) tutorial, but specifically written for ubuntu. I was having trouble getting the other instructions working for gaming.

As mentioned in the other answer, comment out the lines requiring mschap or mppe and it will be un-encrypted. You can use tcpdump to see your plain text packets.